# Qt - Set DockWidget start size

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qdockwidget

I currently working on an project in Qt. This project includes an DockWidget, called "ProjectExplorer". I display this with this technique:
**FPHMainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef FPHMAINWINDOW_H
#define FPHMAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class ProjectExplorer;

namespace Ui {
class FPHMainWindow;
}

class FPHMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FPHMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FPHMainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionNewProject_triggered();

    void on_actionImportProject_triggered();

    void on_actionNew_triggered();

    void on_NEWTB__cancel_clicked();

private:
    Ui::FPHMainWindow *ui;
    ProjectExplorer *mProjectExplorer;
};

#endif // FPHMAINWINDOW_H
```

And in **FPHMainWindow.cpp**:

```
FPHMainWindow::FPHMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FPHMainWindow),
    mProjectExplorer(new ProjectExplorer(this))
{
    // Code...


    /* Adding DockWidgets to MainWindow */
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, mProjectExplorer);

}
```

But now If I start the program it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vAag.png

But I want an size of **Width: 388, Heigth: 477** ***ON START!*** How I can fix this "issue"?

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: the image you post is unclearly. Well I suppose you call to `ui->setupUi( this );` method in the constructor. On the other hand, if you want to setup widget size, you can call to `QWidget::resize( QSize )` or `QWidget::resize( int w, int h )` methods.

Comment: @eferion QWidget::resize(...) doesn't works for me, nothing changes. In the image I mean, in designer the DockWidget has the size I want and by run, the DockWidget hasn't the same size like in designer.

Comment: @Charles44, you can set the minimal size of the inner widget - the one that the dock widget contains.

Comment: You can call `setFixedSize()` too, which sets min, max and the size policy to fixed.

I'm having the same problem, but do not want to set the minimum size, I simply want to remember/restore the size of my `QDockWidgets`.  Restoring state and geometry on my `QMainWindow` does not work either.  My issue seems to be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215897/resize-a-qdockwidget).